# Calculating the number of paths when considering a simple random walk.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $m$ be a positive integer, and consider a simple random walk with $X_0 = 2m$.  Let the random variable $T$ be the time to ruin, and let $N_t$ denote the number of paths which end in ruin at time $t$.  Calculate $N_t$.

Ideally, using the lecture notes we've been provided the way to do this would be to calculate:

$$N_t = N_{t-1}(2m,1)-N_{t-1}^0(2m,1)$$
where $N_{t}^0(a,b) = N_{t}(-a,b)$ and $N_{t}(a,b) = \frac{t!}{n!(t-n)!}$ where $n = (b-a+t)/2$.

When applying to the above equation I arrive at this:

$$N_t = \frac{(t-1)!}{(-m+t/2)!(m+t/2 +1)!}-\frac{(t-1)!}{(m+t/2)!(-m+t/2 -1)!}$$

I am not sure how to simplify this.  Is there a simpler way of doing this? Have I made a mistake? Is there another way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: It seems that our Stochastic-Processes have used slightly different notations. Could you explain a little about what is exactly be ruined and what do the parameters of the function $N_t( a , b )$ mean?